# How to get names of person from webpage in selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, download

From Python I have opened the following webpage:

https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Notices/View-Red-Notices

```
chromedriver_path = r"./driver/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
url = "https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Notices/View-Red-Notices"


topics_xpath = '//*[@id="noticesResultsItemList"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a'
browser.get(url)
escolhe = browser.find_element("xpath", topics_xpath)
time.sleep(10)
escolhe.click()
time.sleep(60)
browser.close()
```

Now, I need to get the names of the people shown in that page.

Does anybody know how to do it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium has a very useful implicit wait feature which means that use of *sleep()* should be redundant. Use of this feature means that Selenium will wait for up to the specified number of seconds for an element to come into existence.

Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

IW = 5
URL = 'https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Notices/View-Red-Notices'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

service = Service('/Volumes/G-Drive/chromedriver')

with webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options) as wbe:
    wbe.implicitly_wait(IW)
    wbe.get(URL)
    if (div := wbe.find_element(By.ID, 'noticesResultsItemList')):
        for sd in div.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'redNoticeItem__labelLink'):
            print(sd.text.replace('\n', ' '))
```

**Output:**

```
PRZYSIUDA MARIUSZ
RIBEIRO ROSANGELA APARECIDA
GOROSITO PEREZ DANIEL PATRICIO
RIFFI RABIE
ESPINOZA CONDORI EDWIN ALFREDO
PINTO GONZÁLEZ TULIO DE JESUS
ZEAS MENDOZA JOSE DAVID
HERNANDEZ CASTRO JOSE IVAN
DE CARVALHO MELO QUIRINO DE MORAIS ELSON
SINGH VIKRAMJEET
CARDONA CABRERA MISRAEL
ABREGO FUENTES JOSE ARMANDO
CORTEZ LOPEZ VICTOR MANUEL
ANGEL FLORES MELVIN JOSSUE
GUEVARA PAZ JAIME AMILCAR
ESCOBAR SÁNCHEZ OSCAR ANTONIO
MENDOZA BELTRAN JOSE ABDON
IBARRA MARTINEZ AURELIO
BOUGUETTAIA ABDELKADER
KOSZCZYK RYSZARD
```

Answer (score 1):

Using WebDriverWait instead of sleeps and numpy to keep the first and last names together:

```
import numpy as np
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']"))
)

names = [item for sublist in np.array_split([x.text.replace("\n", " ") for x in elements], 2) for item in sublist]
print(names)
```

Output:

```
['PRZYSIUDA MARIUSZ', 'RIBEIRO ROSANGELA APARECIDA', 'GOROSITO PEREZ DANIEL PATRICIO', 'RIFFI RABIE', 'ESPINOZA CONDORI EDWIN ALFREDO', 'PINTO GONZÁLEZ TULIO DE JESUS', 'ZEAS MENDOZA JOSE DAVID', 'HERNANDEZ CASTRO JOSE IVAN', 'DE CARVALHO MELO QUIRINO DE MORAIS ELSON', 'SINGH VIKRAMJEET', 'CARDONA CABRERA MISRAEL', 'ABREGO FUENTES JOSE ARMANDO', 'CORTEZ LOPEZ VICTOR MANUEL', 'ANGEL FLORES MELVIN JOSSUE', 'GUEVARA PAZ JAIME AMILCAR', 'ESCOBAR SÁNCHEZ OSCAR ANTONIO', 'MENDOZA BELTRAN JOSE ABDON', 'IBARRA MARTINEZ AURELIO', 'BOUGUETTAIA ABDELKADER', 'KOSZCZYK RYSZARD']
```